# How to specify constraints in visual studio database projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, database-project

Should it be done on the create table script or by adding a separate file under the constraints folder?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as part of the table script.

The actual publish script that is generated will normally change the order a fair bit and will enable the constraints right at the end of the script.

Answer (score 0):

in the table designer(that's when you double-click a table from the server explorer) you can do a right click -> check constraints -> add